# Stumped on calculator operations in C#

Tags: c#, methods, calculator

I was making a calculator using Windows Forms Application and I'm currently stumped.
Here's my application so far, it can only do addition, but any amount of numbers.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int num;
    int answer = 0;
    int i;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void plusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        answer += System.Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);            
        ClearTextbox();
    }

    private void minusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //answer -= System.Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        //ClearTextbox();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void divideButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void multiplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = 1;
        displayInt(num);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = 2;
        displayInt(num);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = 3;
        displayInt(num);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = 4;
        displayInt(num);
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = 5;
        displayInt(num);
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = 6;
        displayInt(num);
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = 7;
        displayInt(num);
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = 8;
        displayInt(num);
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = 9;
        displayInt(num);
    }

    private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = 0;
        displayInt(num);
    }

    private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearTextbox();
        num = 0;
        answer = 0;

    }

    public void displayInt(int num)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + num.ToString();
    }

    public void ClearTextbox()
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
    }

    public void DisplayAnswer(int answer)
    {
        answer += System.Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); //Answer = Answer + Textbox Stuff


        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox1.Text = answer.ToString();
    }

    private void equalsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAnswer(answer);
        num = 0;
        answer = 0;
    }


}
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to wait until another number key is pressed, and then do x + y. I heard about event handlers, but it's quite a vague topic to me.

Here's a picture: http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/4127/12464e13e5154a949a9a457.png

*I want it to be able to do operations to more then 2 numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: All your button_Click routines are event handlers!

Comment: @M.Babcock Nope, doing it for fun.

Comment: I might suggest first making the event handlers consistent with the calculator button numbers.  The 7 button being handled by button_1click is the a sure step on the road to insanity. ;)

Comment: @ArumugaWalters - One more question... Why??? I'm sure your imagination can think of *something* better to do then build YAC (*Yet Another Calculator*).

Comment: @M.Babcock: IMHO a simple calculator is a great exercise for learning certain programming concepts like simple UI, event driven programming, beginning OOP etc. If you have more imaginative ideas along those lines of complexity, please share.

Comment: I just wanted to get the "basics" down. I've created other simple applications and I wanted to step up.

Comment: @PaulSasik- I agree it provides benefit to new programmers. The problem is that it doesn't inspire (which is why I asked if it was homework). Maybe learning to program doesn't involve inspiration or the thrill of (typically false) innovation anymore like it did when I taught myself to program.

Comment: @M.Babcock I see where you're going, but like I stated before, I just wanted to get the basics down because I have an idea for a program but it's a bit to advanced for me at the moment.

Comment: @ArumugaWalters - That deserves a +1 for knowing your boundaries. One thing you have going for you that many of us didn't is having SO available to help you through tough spots. I've been doing this for ~20 years (counting non-professional experience) and I know I didn't have anything like it when I started.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a bit messy and it's hard to figure out your intent. Help with this code will be long in coming. I suggest following [this simple calculator tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s2p15.html). It explains the concepts and steps very nicely, including button events.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a "+"-button and a "="-button. Then your calculator has two number fields and two states:

1) Entering first number

2) Entering second number

You could have a variable saying which number is being entered.

```
int field = 1;
```

When pressing a digit button, this digit has to be appended to the corresponding field.

When pressing the "+"-button change the state to

```
field = 2;
```

Now the digits will be appended to the second field.

When you press the "="-button, convert the two numbers, which are still strings now, to `int`'s, add them and output them to a result field. Set the state back to

```
field = 1;
```

Also a "clear"-button would clear the fields and set `field = 1;`

---

Note: As Paul Sasik says, your code is a bit messy. I would help, if you gave your buttons meaningful names like `btnDigit1`, `btnDigit2`, `btnPlus`, `btnEquals`, `btnClear`. When you double-click a button in the designer an event handler like `btnPlus_Click` will be created. This is clearer than `button17_Click`.